# Sunburst highcharts problem with custom colors and custom tooltip

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts, sunburst-diagram

Here

> 1] I am trying to use custom color scheme instead of default theme
> provided by highcharts. But It is not working as expected.  I have
> implemented colors array and it should serially apply the colors, but
> it is randomizing the color sequence and sometimes even repeating the
> colors.
>
> 2] And also trying to implement custom tool-tip but the code is giving
> an error.

I have created a stackblitz as below:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mz3dhi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,package.json

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for sharing your code - you would need to order your data by the level itself. i.e.

```
data: [
            {
              id: '0.0',
              parent: ' ',
              name: 'Parent',
            },
            {
              id: '1.3',
              parent: '0.0',
              name: 'Steve',
            },
            {
              id: '1.2',
              parent: '0.0',
              name: 'Sam',
            },
            {
              id: '1.1',
              parent: '0.0',
              name: 'Stefy',
            },
            {
              id: '2.1',
              parent: '1.1',
              name: 'Section1',
            },
            ...
            ...
            ...
      ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @Duniyadnd. It may happen if you have some levels missing in between? For eg : parent: '1.1', is there but after that we have parent: '1.3' and parent: '1.2', is missing ?

Comment: And do you know how we can implement custom tool tip over there? Please let me know if you have any idea.

Comment: For the first part (if you have levels missing) - did you try using `null` as a value?

Comment: For the second part - it looks like @Sebastian-hajdus answered that question https://stackoverflow.com/a/74558718/293291

Answer (score 0):

When you use Highcharts in Angular, sometimes you need to extend types, [article](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/highcharts-typescript-declarations#extending-highcharts-in-typescript) about extending Highcharts in typescript.

```
interface extendPointLabelObject extends Highcharts.PointLabelObject {
}


tooltip: {
  formatter: function( this: extendPointLabelObject) {
    return 'custom tooltip'
  }
},
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-nvt2jb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)